# Intercept every exception in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I used exception_notifier gem and Airbrake, but I would like to intercept and send the error, environment and backtrace to a web service. I think I should monkey patch Object::Exception but I am not sure how. I do not want to change the behaviour of Object::Exception but just intercept and send its data. I would like to do it for any Ruby app, so I would like an agnostic solution. If it is not possible a framework-agnostic solution, a Rails solution is better than nothing, but I guess I could study the exception_notification gem.

Answer (score 3):

For Rails, you can put the following in `application_controller.rb`:

```
rescue_from Exception do |e|
  # do whatever you want with the exception
  # and if you still want the exception to continue propagating, then:
  raise e
end
```